# Ionic 2: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../package.json"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm working on integrating Woocommerce Rest API with Ionic 2 using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce-api

First I installed the package:

```
npm install --save woocommerce-api
```

Then installed typings for node: ( typings version 2.x )

```
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

Import in Page class

```
import * as WooCommerceAPI from 'woocommerce-api';
```

Initialize the package:

```
ngOnInit() {
    var WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
      url: 'http://example.com',
      consumerKey: 'ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      consumerSecret: 'cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    });
 }
```

I'm getting this error and app stops running.

[image]

Project Structure:

[image]

If I comment the code in ngOnInit function, then app runs fine. This is problem with woocommerce-api node package. How to fix this?

Comment: check if the package.json file exists

Comment: Can you post the package.json and  app folder structure.

Comment: @Ladmerc yes package.json exists.

Comment: @AvramVirgil Added folder structure.